# Question about the Location of user controls of a window form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window form application (C# framework 3.5) with several textboxes, buttons and labels. When I install the application in different machines (same OS version both XP & vista), the user controls sometimes shifted down and dislocated  while sometimes they come out perfectly fine....

What is the factor for the dislocation? the screen resolution? the screen size?

Is there any way to prevent this happen?

Please help!!

Comment: Can you provide screen shots?

Comment: Screen shots would help here. Since I think that you can't add images to a post (not enough reputation), just put the pictures online somewhere (photobucket or similar) and put the URL's in the post and someone will fix that for you.

Comment: Provide with the screen shot

<table style="width:auto;"><tr><td><a href="http://picasaweb.google.com.hk/lh/photo/TWofrLk1zuW6aCjXnpx3zg?feat=embedwebsite"><img src="http://lh4.ggpht.com/_E7Tg_YxPyUQ/SixpLkQp6WI/AAAAAAAAB08/zjp2P9zMVRA/s144/shift.jpg" /></a></td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-size:11px; text-align:right">From <a href="http://picasaweb.google.com.hk/shipchan/Public?feat=embedwebsite">public</a></td></tr></table>

or link for the screen shot
http://picasaweb.google.com.hk/lh/photo/TWofrLk1zuW6aCjXnpx3zg?feat=directlink

Answer (score 0):

Check the Display Properties for each machine, by right-clicking on the desktop and selecting Properties from the menu.  I think, based on your description, that it has to do with different themes/font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in Display Properties, the DPI setttings can have an effet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever using the `Control.Size` property of a Form for layout purposes? Remember that the `Control.ClientSize` property returns the size of the area that you can actually work in. `Size` includes the window decoration which can be different depending on OS settings.

Are you using a `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Are you familiar with how the `Control.Anchor` property works?